# MIPS Random 4 digit HEX generation

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to generate a random 4 digit HEX number with all the digits different.
For ex: **123A, F451, ABCD**, etc.

I need help with **generation** only(I think I can figure out how to make them all different)

Please, help! Thank you.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the MARS simulator, syscalls 40 through 44 have to do with generating random numbers.

[Docs here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html).

Answer (score 0):

see solution here:
Generate random hex number with 4 distinct digits in MIPS:
https://studyacer.com/solution/generate-random-hex-number-with-4-distinct-digits-in-mips-10955

Answer (score 0):

see solution here: Generate random hex number with 4 distinct digits in MIPS:
new address:
https://studyacer.com/solution/generate-random-hex-number-with-4-distinct-digits-get-user-hex-number-10649

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: do not post links here! and Read FAQ before answering!